# Converting DNA sequences into pixel images

Tags: text, pixel

I have a text file of DNA sequences, more than 3 billions characters of four letters - A, T, C and G-. 
I'd like to have an image of this file and convert each character into a right pixel image. I greatly appreciate your comments? any software to do so?

Comment: I'm afraid this must be a naive question: what is a *right pixel image*?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my main question was how to convert a text file like this:

ATCGAATTCCGGAAATACGATCGGCTCA...
to an image?

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a way. My answer at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/14184/how-does-deepvariant-construct-rgb-images-from-dna-sequences would help.

`In RGB, each dimension is an NxN image. Since you have three dimensions, so it's 3xNxN. The red dimension was used to encode the nucleotide bases. The green dimension was used to encode quality scores. Finally, the blue dimension was used to encode the strand information.`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what that four letters mean but:
1) Assign each of them a color.You have four colors for the four letters.
2) Obviously you would kill the PC if you read the whole file and stores it on RAM, so you should read it in chunks. 
3) So, lets say you will display it on a 1024x768 monitor, then 3,000,000,000/1024=2,929,687.5 ; that is the size of your chunks. 
I would:
 
-1: read the first 2,929,688 letters of your file.

-2: create a global RGB var that could be an array which stores 3 doubles.
 
-3: for each letter, I divide it's color on its RGB components and add its to the global RGB component, for example:
//letterRGB={red:255,green:125,blue:255};
globalRGB["red"]+=letterRGB["red"]/255; //gives 1 
globalRGB["green"]+=letterRGB["green"]/255; // gives 0.5
globalRGB["blue"]+=letterRGB["blue"]/255;//gives 1

-4: divide each component for the number of points,  and then multiply that for 255. This would give you the color of the chunck. For example:
globalRGB["red"]=Math.round((globalRGB["red"]/nPoints)*255);//nPoints=2,929,688 

So here you are basically calculating the average color of the whole  2,929,688 letters, and thats the color of only 1 point (or pixel) in your screen, one of the 1024 points.
I would repeat the process with the next 2,929,688 leters  until I get my 1024 chunks represented.
Lets suppose your user clicks on one point (or chunck) on the screen.Your system should zoom in, and the way to do that is repeating this whole process but only for the 2,929,688 letters on that point.
So your chunks would be made of 2,929,688/1024=2861 points only. And so one. I bet you alredy got the logic.

 It should be a point when, by zooming, the user could see one by one the different letters represented in different colors, ordered in the secuence.

Let me know what you think about this, and good luck.